# Jquery sorting with swap

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 9 (3 row and 3 columns) div elements in my web page, where i implemented jquery sortable method, when user take any element to another i will need to swap instead of sorting. for ex, if i take 1st element to 5th, 1st should go 5th position and 5th one should go 1st position basically it is swapping.

I have achieved this by finding current and old index of the element getting moved at sortstop event and inserting element based on index. But i have below issue.

for ex: when user takes 1st element to 5th, sorting happens before i manually do swap, so user feel that when mouse is not released on sorting, the result is different(2nd will take position of 1st and 3rd will go 2nd etc..) in actual swap as i do swap on sorting stop event.

Please let me know if there are any workaround for this.

Regards,

M.Seenuvasan

My Code below:

### script

```
    $("#sortable").sortable({

        handle: '.portlet-header'
    });


$("#sortable").on("sortstop", function (event, ui) {

var currentPortid = ui.item.attr("id");
    var currentIndex = ui.item.index();

var oldIndex = -1;
    var oldPortid = "";

//to get old index, this array will hold all the index while page load and update based on swap
    for (i = 0; i < PortletIndex.length; i++) {
        if (PortletIndex[i][0] == currentPortid) {
            oldIndex = PortletIndex[i][1];
        }
        if (PortletIndex[i][1] == currentIndex) {
            oldPortid = PortletIndex[i][0];
        }
    }

$($("#sortable div.portlet")[oldIndex]).after($("#" + oldPortid));

});
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="sortable">
            <div id="myportlet1" class="portlet sortable row1" >
                <div class="portlet-header">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="myportlet2" class="portlet sortable row1" >
                <div class="portlet-header">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="myportlet3" class="portlet sortable row1" >
                <div class="portlet-header">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="myportlet4" class="portlet sortable row2" >
                <div class="portlet-header">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="myportlet5" class="portlet sortable row2" >
                <div class="portlet-header">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="myportlet6" class="portlet sortable row2" >
                <div class="portlet-header">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="myportlet7" class="portlet sortable row3" >
                <div class="portlet-header" >

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="myportlet8" class="portlet sortable row3" >
                <div class="portlet-header">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="myportlet9" class="portlet sortable row3" >
                <div class="portlet-header">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you really have code to post? Making a mockup in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be much better.

Comment: Hi jai, i have added code